# Is there a way to change Windows' maximize button behavior?

Tags: windows, window, gui, window-manager, powertoys

I would like to make maximize button leave a border that makes the wallpaper be seen on the edges of my screen similar to this screenshot.
[image]

My workaround right now is using PowerToys' FancyZones but I want to know if there is a more seamless way to do this.

Comment: You might point out that this is windows 11.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this functionality with [Aerial](https://github.com/ChrisAnd1998/Aerial).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1128004)